# What is the maximum of fields a Google form can contain?

Tags: google-forms

I read on [Google Docs, Sheets, and Slides size limits](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/37603?hl=en) that spreadsheets have a maximum of columns per sheet.

Shall I conclude that the maximum of fields a Google Form can contain is 255 (since one column is reserved for the timestamp)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorrect. The current version of Google Forms has an independent form responses repository. Sending form responses to Google Sheets is optional.

Form responses could be downloaded as CSV from the Google Forms. Also they could be retrieved by using Google Apps Script.

It's worth to mention that Google hasn't disclosed Google Forms limits but there are reports of forms having a large number of questions (+300) that can't be responded.

The practical limit could be affected the type of questions if the form loads all the questions on a single page or if it uses sections to split questions into several pages.

Related

- [Google Spreadsheet column limit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/30234/88163)

Answer (score 5):

Correct - Google Forms utilizes Google Spreadsheets to store their data, so you are restricted to the limits imposed on Spreadsheets.

**EDIT:**

As Jacob pointed out, these limits only apply to old Google Spreadsheets. All limits have been removed in the new version.

> All spreadsheet limits mentioned above have been removed in [the new
>   version of Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3541068). The new version of Google Sheets should
>   support 2 million cells of data, though please note that extremely
>   large spreadsheets may have slower performance. Learn more about
>   [switching to the new version of Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3544847).

[Google Help Article](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/37603?rd=1)

Comment: Technically you are correct, but the references Franck added are based on the old Google Spreadsheets. With the new Sheets, restrictions are based on the number of cells, being 2 million. You should be able to add more than 255 columns, as long as you are below the 2m.

Comment: Good catch - updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a practical limit to how long a section can be, I use 50 questions max. There is also a maximum runtime for a script and so the total questions you can create using Google Apps Script is less than 500 questions. Beyond that length the form page simply won't respond in time and Google will timeout the request before finishing.

Google may allow you to create any size form, but with Apps Script it will not function beyond a few hundred questions.

Comment: Have you tried to use sections in order to limit the number of questions been loaded?

Comment: @Rubén Do I just add a section header to create a new section?

Comment: The terms could vary depending on the English variant that is being used. On the one that I use It's just "section" not "section header" (in my case there is a form element type named Title)

Comment: @Rubén you just create a section header and it creates a section. That is the API.