# Google Sheets column limit?

Tags: google-sheets

I have 137 columns (EG).  I cannot scroll to the right of column EG.  I have many rows, but only 37 used rows.

Reading what I can find via searches, it seems I should not be facing this restriction.  Does anyone have a suggested workaround?

Comment: There is a limit of 2,000,000 cells in the spreadsheet, used or not. For example, 137 columns with 15,000 rows would already exceed it. Reduce the number of rows and try again.

Comment: @user135384 Is the limit really 2,000,000 or is it actually 2,097,152?

Comment: @Michael [Google says 2 million](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en), and the other limits on that page are in multiples of 10. Those are intentionally imposed quotas, not technical limitations.

Answer (score 7):

## Short answer

The limit of columns is 18278, the last possible column is column ZZZ:ZZZ. It's very likely that the OP issue isn't directly related to the number of columns but something else that if affecting the web browser or computer like an extension, the lack of enough resources to handle the spreadsheet, etc.

## Explanation

According to [Files you can store in Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en) Google Sheets has 5 million cells limit by spreadsheet<sup>*</sup>.  One could think that the limit consider all the spreadsheet cells, no matter of how many sheets / rows / columns are being used.

Validation

I tested the above by trying to insert a 1,999,999 columns to a spreadsheet that contains a single sheet with a single cell (A1) by using the following script:

```
function test() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().insertColumns(1, 1999999)
}
```

When I run it, the following error message was shown:

> This action would increase the number of columns in the sheet above the limit of 18278 columns. (line 2, file "Code")

---

Notes:

<sup>*</sup> As of December 9th, 2021 the cell limit is 10 million.

I discovered this accidentally when running a script and later I was able to reproduce the error message by using the following script on a spreadsheet having a single sheet, with a single column having 1000 cells.

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.insertRowsAfter(1000,10E6-1000);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  console.log(sheet.getMaxRows());
  sheet.insertRows(1);
  
}
```

Execution Logs

```
10:01:43 PM Notice  Execution started
10:01:45 PM Info    10000000
10:01:57 PM Error   
Exception: This action would increase the number of cells in the workbook above the limit of 10000000 cells.
myFunction  @ Code.gs:6
```

The [official help article](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603) still mentions 5 million as the cell limit.

---

Related questions:

- [Google Spreadsheet column limit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/30234/88163)
- [Can Google Spreadsheets handle 10 million rows?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/65635/88163)

Comment: 18278 is a weird, non-intuitive limit for a computer system...

Comment: @Micheal Not weird. It's the column of "ZZZ:ZZZ"

Comment: The current limit is 5M though.

Answer (score 2):

I just deleted the extra rows and columns in a few worksheets and it worked! It frees up the cells.